Determining the distance to an emission from "plume width" assuming a plume is gaussian
I am measuring pollutant concentrations, from a source downwind, using aircraft data. Occasionally, I observe an enhancement related to an upwind emission, and this enhancement lasts for some amount of time or some distance traveled by the aircraft.
I am assuming that these upwind plumes can be described as gaussian, and given this I am curious how I can, using the "width" of enhancement (or the amount of distance over which I observe an enhancement above background), relate this quantity to the distance my measured point is from the plume origin.
I have been approaching this using the gaussian plume model equation so far, but my education in this topic is lackluster and I have not been able to obtain a solution. Any help would be appreciated.


Welcome BRCTAYTAY to Physics Stack Exchange.  Some additional clarification and details would be useful.   Are you assuming the initial release is a point source in space and time, and it expands by diffusion or turbulence as it moves through the air? A sketch showing source, wind direction, airplane, and emission cloud might help.

@DavidBailey Thank you for the welcome. Yes, I'm assuming an initial release point at the ground that expands by dispersion as it moves through the air from the origin to the point of measurement. Probably in a moderately unstable atmosphere. I'm attaching a diagram now.

When you say you "have not been able to obtain a solution", is the problem mathematical or that the gaussian plume model does not match your observational data? In either case, more explanation of the problem might help.
